# Which is faster in sql: searching for a table, or searching for data in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Say there are 1,000 tables in a database, and each table has 1,000 rows.  When I search for single table from these 1,000 tables, is the search time same as that required to search for data within one of the tables?

In other words, does SQL use the same search algorithm to find a table out of 1,000 tables as it does to get data from a table with 1,000 rows?

Comment: How would you go about searching for a table? `select * from information_schema.tables`? A table is a table is a table.

Comment: If you have 1000 tables that have the same structure, you need to read up on database design. If you don't know what table you want to get data from because they are different, then you need to get more familiar with your database design and you are not qualified to query it until you do know what each table does and understand the meaning of teh data. You do not generally ever write queries to look for tables.

Comment: I would bet you have made a rooky mistake in your database design. Why would you want to search for a table, please explain

Comment: @HLGEM  I am passing the table name, and its being received by a variable    select * from $tableName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MySQL doesn't use the same search algorithm to find a table.

MySQL maintains an in-memory "data dictionary" so when you run a query that names a specific table, it looks up that table very quickly. It's much faster for MySQL to identify a table than to search for data within a table. For example, the database servers I maintain at my job have over 150,000 tables, and this isn't a problem.

Does this mean you should split up your data over many tables to make it run faster? **No** -- that's not usually a good tradeoff. It makes your application code more complex, since your code needs to pick which table to query. You may also find cases where you wish the data were in one table, if you have to search for results across many of your tables.

Here are a couple of principles to follow:

> "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler."  [(attributed to Albert Einstein)](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/)
>
> "First make it work, then make it right, and, finally, make it fast." (Stephen C. Johnson and Brian W. Kernighan, 1983)

Comment: . . Why isn't the time essentially the same as the time to locate a record in a similarly sized table, using a primary key when the data is in memory?

Comment: Thank you.....this was the answer i needed

Comment: @GordonLinoff, searching a primary key is a B-tree traversal, with O(log n) complexity. Searching a hash index of tables is O(1) complexity.